# HQL return data types

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am using hibernate to get data from my psql database. I have some problems with constructors. What data type does hql return with COUNT(*) and MONTH(date) functions?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count(*) will return Long.
MONTH(date) will return Integer.

Comment: http://dev.anyframejava.org/docs.en/anyframe/plugin/hibernate/4.6.1/reference/html/ch06.html

Comment: I failed to find anything about return types there. Could you post a quote please?